# C# Service Collection adds type as object rather than its actual type

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, json-deserialization, servicecollection

I'm having a little issue with my code.

Basically, I'm trying to dynamically add classes that I've created from deserializing JSON into my ServiceCollection, so I can get them from any class that needs them. So far I've got the following code:

```cs
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().Where(t => t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(AbstractConfiguration)) && !t.IsAbstract).ToList().ForEach(x => {
    if (!File.Exists(x.Name + ".json")) {
        object Configuration = Activator.CreateInstance(x);
        File.WriteAllText(x.Name + ".json", JsonSerializer.Serialize(Configuration, new JsonSerializerOptions() { WriteIndented = true }));
        ServiceCollection.AddSingleton(Configuration);
     } else {
        string json = File.ReadAllText(x.Name + ".json");
        object Configuration = JsonSerializer.Deserialize(json, x, new JsonSerializerOptions() { WriteIndented = true });
        ServiceCollection.AddSingleton(Configuration);
    }
});
```

We load up our JSON into a class (which works), add it into our collection (which works), however; when adding into our collection the type is an object, so when I try call it through `Services.GetServices(typeof(BotConfiguration)).ToList().Count);`, it returns 0. What gives?

Well, if we instead try run `Services.GetServices(typeof(object)).ToList().ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x.ToString()));`, we can actually see that this instantiation actually falls under the *object* type, even though when we run x.ToString(), it shows that it is an instance of BotConfiguration (outputs Dexter.Core.Configurations.BotConfiguration in my case).

How would we get our ServiceCollection to add this as its actual class rather than an object? It clearly knows what type it is...?

Comment: This sounds awfully similar to using `IOptions` with JSON files: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49046847/5803406

Comment: I was going to go with IOptions but looking over the code for it gave me a bit of a headache lmao, so I decided to go with (what was in my opinion) as simpler solution - which worked until I moved most of my project over to being instanced by Microsoft's dependency injection, as the main library I used requried it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code is calling generic version of method (`AddSingleton<TService>(IServiceCollection, TService)`) with generic type parameter being resolved at compile time to `object`, try calling one accepting `Type` parameter (see all [overloads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.servicecollectionserviceextensions.addsingleton?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_ServiceCollectionServiceExtensions_AddSingleton_Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_IServiceCollection_System_Type_)) like this:

```
ServiceCollection.AddSingleton(x);
```

**UPD**

There is overload (`AddSingleton(IServiceCollection, Type, Object)`) accepting type and object instance:

```
ServiceCollection.AddSingleton(x, Configuration);
```

Comment: The problem is that this instance has variables in it which have been initialized by the JSON deserialization code, which would be needed to accessed.

Comment: Ah lord, you're a saviour mate lmao. Thanks!

Comment: @Frostrix was glad to help!