# ASP.NET CORE: IConfiguration can not access ConnectionString inside Class Library

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, dbcontext, argumentnullexception

I have a class library for a Repository to handle the Database operation, and I tried to create `DbContext` and set ConnectionString as well, but it did not work.

```
    namespace CoreCrud.Repository
    {
        public class CoreCrudDBContext: DbContext
        {
            private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
            public CoreCrudDBContext(DbContextOptions<CoreCrudDBContext> options, IConfiguration configuration) : base(options)
            {
                _configuration = configuration;
            }
    
            protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
            {
                String connString = _configuration.GetConnectionString("CoreCrudDatabase");
                Console.WriteLine(connString);
    
                if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
                    optionsBuilder.UseMySQL(connString);
            }
    
            public DbSet<Person> person { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

I also have `appsettings.json`:

```
    {
      "ConnectionStrings": {
        "CoreCrudDatabase": "server=localhost;database=core_crud;user=root;password=password"
      }
    }
```

And the DbContext is defined in `Startup.cs` in web mvc project as follows:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
            {
                services.AddControllersWithViews();
                services.AddDbContext<CoreCrudDBContext>();
            }
```

But each time the project runs it gives this error:
`optionsBuilder.UseMySQL(connString);` inside `OnConfiguring` method.

`System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'connectionString')'`

Comment: Have you confirmed that your app startup adds that file to the configuration? If this is the first thing you’ve put in that JSON file then it’s an easy thing to miss.

Comment: @ScottHannen yes repository class library is added as dependency to web mvc project and the dbcontext also added to startup for di.

Comment: But in your startup, do you specify that `IConfiguration` should include that file? `.AddJsonFile("somefile.json")`Not doing that can produce the result you're seeing. It's in the file, but that file isn't being used.

Comment: @ScottHannen you mean startup on web mvc project right?

Comment: Yes, Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49046847/how-can-i-add-a-custom-json-file-into-iconfiguration

Comment: @ScottHannen ok, thanks i'll look into it.